# Mocking EntityFramework queries containing navigation properties with Moq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to setup unit and integration tests for our repository/unit of work framework. Mocking the queries work fine until navigation properties are introduced. The following works fine:

```
var customers = (from cus in Customers.GetAll()
                    join acm in AccountManagers.GetAll() on cus.INS_Id equals acm.INS_Id
                    join the in Employees.GetAll() on acm.THE_Id equals the.THE_Id

                    select new CustomerModel()
                    {
                        Id = cus.INS_Id,
                        Name = cus.INS_Name,
                        OrganizationNumber = cus.INS_OrgNo,
                        PostalAddress = cus.INS_PostalAddress1,
                        PostalCity = cus.INS_PostalCity,
                        ...
```

However, adding a line to the the select like this, will not work:

```
var customers = (from cus in Customers.GetAll()
                    join acm in AccountManagers.GetAll() on cus.INS_Id equals acm.INS_Id
                    join the in Employees.GetAll() on acm.THE_Id equals the.THE_Id

                    select new CustomerModel()
                    {
                        Id = cus.INS_Id,
                        Name = cus.INS_Name,
                        OrganizationNumber = cus.INS_OrgNo,
                        PostalAddress = cus.INS_PostalAddress1,
                        PostalCity = cus.INS_PostalCity,
                        Brokered = cus.InsuredBrokers.Any(),
                        ...
```

The reason is that `cus.InsuredBrokers` is a navigation property, and Moq does not know what to do with it.

I have setup the tests like this:

```
// Sets up a new Mock DbSet, given a list of inmemory data
private Mock<DbSet<T>> SetupSet<T>(IQueryable<T> data) where T : class
{
    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

    return mockSet;
}

// Sets up a new Mock DbContext with a given Mock DbSet of data
private Mock<PrositContext> SetupContext<T>(Mock<DbSet<T>> set) where T : class
{
    var mockContext = new Mock<PrositContext>();
    mockContext.Setup(m => m.Set<T>()).Returns(set.Object);

    return mockContext;
}

// Adds a given Mock DbSet of data to an existing Mock DbContext
private Mock<PrositContext> SetupContext<T>(Mock<DbSet<T>> set, Mock<PrositContext> existingContext) where T : class
{
    existingContext.Setup(m => m.Set<T>()).Returns(set.Object);

    return existingContext;
}

// Sets up a new Mock DbContext given a list of inmemory data
private Mock<PrositContext> SetupContext<T>(IQueryable<T> data) where T : class
{
    var mockSet = SetupSet(data);
    return SetupContext(mockSet);
}

// Adds to an existing Mock DbContext a list of inmemory data
private Mock<PrositContext> SetupContext<T>(IQueryable<T> data, Mock<PrositContext> existingContext) where T : class
{
    var mockSet = SetupSet(data);
    return SetupContext(mockSet, existingContext);
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestGetCustomerName()
{
    // ARRANGE

    // Read the data from a .csv file
    var customerData = new CsvCustomerRepository(null).GetAll();
    var accountManagerData = new CsvAccountManagerRepository(null).GetAll();
    var employeeData = new CsvTHEmployeeRepository(null).GetAll();
    var nrsData = new CsvNordicRiskSolutionsRepository(null).GetAll();
    var inbData = new CsvInsuredBrokersRepository(null).GetAll();
    var gsiData = new CsvGeneralSystemInfoRepository(null).GetAll();

    // Setup the mock context with all the data from the .csv
    var mockContext = SetupContext(customerData);
    SetupContext(accountManagerData, mockContext);
    SetupContext(employeeData, mockContext);
    SetupContext(nrsData, mockContext);
    SetupContext(inbData, mockContext);
    SetupContext(gsiData, mockContext);

    var customerFacade = new CustomerFacade(mockContext.Object);

    // ACT

    var customers = customerFacade.GetByNameMOCKFORTESTING("Bos");

    // ASSERT

    //Assert.AreEqual(...);
}

public IEnumerable<ICustomerModel> GetByNameMOCKFORTESTING(string name)
{
    var customers = (from cus in Customers.GetAll()
                        join acm in AccountManagers.GetAll() on cus.INS_Id equals acm.INS_Id
                        join the in Employees.GetAll() on acm.THE_Id equals the.THE_Id
                        where cus.INS_Name.Contains(name)
                        select new CustomerModel()
                        {
                            Id = cus.INS_Id,
                            Name = cus.INS_Name,
                            OrganizationNumber = cus.INS_OrgNo,
                            PostalAddress = cus.INS_PostalAddress1,
                            PostalCity = cus.INS_PostalCity,
                            Brokered = cus.InsuredBrokers.Any(),
                            CustomerResponsible = new THEmployeeModel()
                            {
                                FirstName = the.THE_FirstName,
                                LastName = the.THE_LastName,
                                PhoneNumber = null
                            },
                            RiskClass = cus.INS_RiskKlass,
                        }).Take(300).ToList();

    return customers;
}
```

What do I need to do to mock that `cus.InsuredBrokers`? Examples, videos and tutorials I find do not touch on the subject of navigation properties, even though they are in common use...

Answer (score 1):

Mocking entity framework is quite difficult. Even if you succeed mocking navigation properties, what about sequences or code that uses lazy-loading. You will end up writing huge mock setups for your tests.

We had a similar problem and solved it using [Effort](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Effort), an EF-provider for an in-memory database. You can set up the database for your tests and only need to mock the creation of your unit of work.